# How can I get multi-language pages to switch based on browser language settings on HubSpot?

Tags: javascript, hubspot, hreflang

I have a website on HubSpot where I've created multi-language variants on some of the pages. The default pages are for the United Kingdom while the variants are for users in the United States.

I understand that HubSpot does not switch languages automatically based on IP or browser settings. I want the pages to switch to the US version of the page when the user's browser language settings (hreflang) are set to the US. Not every page, however, has a US variant.

I tried to implement this JavaScript code to achieve that:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
    var supportedLanguages = ['en-us', 'en']; // Replace with your supported languages
    var defaultLanguage = 'en-us'; // Replace with your default language

    // Check if the browser language is supported, otherwise redirect to the default language
    if (supportedLanguages.indexOf(userLang) === -1) {
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/' + defaultLanguage + window.location.pathname;
    }
</script>
```

I tested it by changing my browser language settings to the US and then clicking on the default link. The link loads incorrectly as https://example/en-us/en-us/blog/examplepost instead of https://example/en-us/blog/examplepost